# finding all series within an array

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, combinations, series

How do I find number of all the series (combinations of an array that have at least 3 consecutive values, like [7,8,9]) and have the longest number of values?

from [3,4,1,2,2] it would be 2 - ([1,2,3,4] twice, but ignore [1,2,3]*2 and [2,3,4]*2)

from [9,6,7,5,8] it would be 1 - ([5,6,7,8,9])

from [1,2,3,1,2] it would be 4 ([1,2,3] * 3)

Thanks

---

**edit**

the point of this is to count runs in a crib hand. It doesn't matter what order the array has the series in, as long as the series counted don't overlap all cards.

---

**edit 1**

```
var $cards:Array = [9, 4, 3, 2, 2];
var $ranks:Array = [];
var $c:int;
for each ($c in $cards) {
    if ($ranks[$c] == null) {
        $ranks[$c] = 1;
    }else {
        $ranks[$c] ++;
    }
}
```

this will create an array ($ranks) that will have these values `[2:2, 3:1, 4:1, 9:1]`

from this I will be able to multiply the values under 2,3 ad4 4 and multiply them by 3, so I would get 2*1*1 * 3

I'm trying to figure out now how to find the consecutive values, and ignore ones that aren't (like the 9)

Comment: Consecutive from the start of the Array or from anywhere ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this works:
it's using casalib for min/max, but there are other ways around it. this onlu finds the largest set of consecutive numbers though, as it is meant to count a crib hand which has a max of 5 cards, thus no two simultaneous series are possible (like 2,3,4 and 9,10,11)

```
private function countRuns($cards:Array):int {
    var $ranks:Array = [];
    var $c:int;

    for each ($c in $cards) {
        if ($ranks[$c] == null) {
            $ranks[$c] = 1;
        }else {
            $ranks[$c] ++;
        }
    }

    var $highest:int = ArrayUtil.getHighestValue($cards);
    var $lowest:int = ArrayUtil.getLowestValue($cards);
    var $seq:Array = [];
    var $longest:Array = [];
    for (var i:int = $lowest; i <= $highest; i++) {
        if ($ranks[i] != null) {
            $seq.push($ranks[i]);
            if ($seq.length > $longest.length && $seq.length > 2) {
                $longest = $seq.concat();
            }
        }else {
            $seq = [];
        }
    }

    var $total:int = $longest.length;
    for each ($c in $longest) {
        $total *= $c;
    }
    trace($total, $cards);
    return $total;
}
```

I found the consecutive numbers through the $seq array, by pushing values whenever the $ranks[i] has a value, if the length is greater than 3 and grater than the $longest array, copy the array over (with concat()!), if there is no value, $seq gets reset.

it's so simple once you know...

---

**edit**
I noticed I had a typo in the code

`if ($seq.length > $longest.length || $seq.length >= 2)`

should have been

`if ($seq.length > $longest.length && $seq.length > 2)`

Comment: @Daniel. You could use the built-in `Math.max` and `Math.min` functions, since they accept `rest` arguments. `Math.max.apply(null,$cards);`

Comment: You could also sort $cards using $cards.sort() and then grab the first and last.

Comment: this is a cool trick, didn't know about this. I looked at casalib to see how that's done (lowest)`return inArray[inArray.sort(16|8)[0]];`. I'm curious how it compares with the Math.min

Comment: @Nicholas, looks like that's what http://as3.casalib.org/docs/org_casalib_util_ArrayUtil.html is doing

Comment: Yeah, I ran your function by sorting $cards first line, and then setting $highest and $lowest using $cards.length -1, and 0

Comment: @Daniel. Honestly, I think that's about the worst possible way to get the max or min value of an array. Not only you have to make a copy first (sort works in-place) but you also have to go all the way sorting it just to get a value. If for some reason you want to code it by hand it's way simpler to assume the first value is the min (or max) and then test every other value in the array: if it's less than the previous value (let's call it `minVal`), assign it to `minVal`. After your loop completes, `minVal` will contain the minimun value.

Answer (score 2):

You want to order your values and replace all duplicates with an array of themselves. ie.

```
//Order values and group matches
[3,4,1,2,2] = [1,[2,2],3,4]
[9,6,7,5,8] = [5,6,7,8,9]
[1,2,3,1,2] = [[1,1],[2,2],3]
```

Then you will want to find the largest consecutive sequence and remove violations.

```
//remove violations (6,7,8)... which I guess you also want to count separately.
[1,[2,2],3,4,6,7,8] = [1,[2,2],3,4]
```

Then it will be a matter of multiplying the length of all of your arrays to find your score.

Once you have cleaned your array, you can think of the formula like this.

```
array2 = [2,2];
array1 = [1, array2, 3, 4];
score = array1.length * array2.length = 8;

array3 = [3,3,3];
array2 = [2,2];
array1 = [1, array2, array3, 4];
score = array1.length * array2.length * array3.length = 24;
```

It should be pretty fun figuring out how to write this in code.

Comment: I've gotten so-far, just not sure how to check whether the sequence is in order, I'll edit post to show what I got so-far (edit 1)

Comment: you can use array.sortOn to put it in order.

Comment: but it doesn't tell me that 9 is the odd one out

Comment: check my solution, I got the code to work for 5 cards, which is enough for my needs. But it would be possible to extend it for multiple sequences by logging all the $longest arrays just before the sequence is interrupted